# Testing Google Play Real Time Notification with purchase flow

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console, google-play-developer-api, google-developer-tools

I am implementing the real time notifications for my app. I see that in the developer documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications they have asked to test by using `Send Test Message` from the Pub/Sub topic. Is there a way to do that by testing subscription purchase through my test staging app or while testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a test message while testing, or at any time, manually from the Developer Console.

In your console select your application and then pick the "Services & APIs" item from the "Development Tools" item on the menu and in the "Real-time developer notifications" section there's a "Send Test Message" button.

Answer (score 0):

Each app has it's own setup for Real time notifications in Monetization setup. So if you have test app submited, you can setup different pubsub topic for it, and not the one for prod. If that's the question.